Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 in iOS
Previously, I am using simple legacy FCM APIs to send a notification to device token but now firebase has updated it to HTTP v1. Now my concern is how can I update it to my Swift app?
I was sending notification through this code previously:
let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        
        let paramString: [String : Any] = ["to" : token,
                                           "priority" : "high",
                                           "notification" : ["title" : title, "body" : body],
        ]
        
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("key=\(serverKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)  { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let jsonData = data {
                    if let jsonDataDict  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDict))")
                        debugPrint(jsonDataDict.description)
                    }
                }
            } catch let err as NSError {
                debugPrint(err.debugDescription)
                debugPrint(err.localizedDescription)
                debugPrint(err)
            }
        }
        task.resume()

I searched a lot to convert it to HTTP v1 but didn't get any article related to that. There are different articles to convert it to PHP, Android, Laravel etc. but for iOS there is no such article. Does any one know how to do this as I am stuck in this from the last week?
